# How to compute hash like MD5(str1+ MD5(str2+ str3))

Tags: c#, encryption, md5

I need to encrypt credentials in order to connect to a remote server.
From the documentation I found, that the password needs to be hashed like shown below.

```
MD5(session + MD5(username+ password))
```

However I wasn't able to get the same hashed password from C#, as sent from the WebClient to the server.

I tried several combination, none of those gave me the same result.
Here is my last approach.

```
string EncryptPassword(string UserName, string Password, string SessionId)
        {
            // Password is MD5(sessionId + MD5(login + password))
            // Source: https://www.godo.dev/tutorials/csharp-md5/
            using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
            {

                string credentials = $"{UserName}{Password}";
                // Hash credentials first
                md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials));
                var inputBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SessionId).ToList();
                inputBuffer.AddRange(md5.Hash);
                //var inputBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SessionId + credentialBuilder.ToString());

                md5.ComputeHash(inputBuffer.ToArray());

                //md5.TransformBlock(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length, inputBuffer, 0);
                //md5.TransformFinalBlock(new byte[0], 0, 0);

                // Get hash result after compute it  
                byte[] hashedCredentials = md5
                    .Hash;

                StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < hashedCredentials.Length; i++)
                {
                    //change it into 2 hexadecimal digits  
                    //for each byte  
                    strBuilder.Append(hashedCredentials[i].ToString("x2"));
                }
                return strBuilder.ToString();
            }
        }
```

I tried with following test credentials:
username:

```
login: TestUser
password: TestPassword
session: uu2cO7b7drhxHKItfRpcJ4#qk@230#$R
```

Valid result: `4dfb147da0d2338cb57e05d1b4b21d07`  <= this is how it should like with the infos above.

My result: `eb55ef7e70c160ad2dd8fe831a1cf708`

Comment: What is `SecureStringHelper.ConvertToString(Password)`? A question should contain a [mre] which could be tested directly.

Comment: MD5 gives you a byte[], SessionID seems to be a string. You convert the byte[] to string using Hex. But who said so? Why not convert to base64? Why not convert the string to byte[] instead? The specification is incomplete.

Comment: @jps sorry for the incomplete example. The `SecureStringHelper` just converts a `SecureString` back to a string. So basically, you also can pass directly a 'string' for the Password parameter to test it.

Comment: @ThomasWeller well, the only information I have is that the Hash needs to look like `MD5(session + MD5(username+ password))`. All three parameters are strings and I used an example (link in the method) which I found in google. So I didn't know exactly what the right approach was for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your result requires you to use the textual (hexadecimal) hash result of UserNamePassword, whereas you're using the byte result.

If you replace:

```
inputBuffer.AddRange(md5.Hash);
```

with:

```
string hexHash = BitConverter.ToString(md5.Hash).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLowerInvariant();
inputBuffer.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hexHash));
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/XJCC18906)

P.S. On the off chance that you're using .NET Core or .NET 5, Microsoft recommend against using `SecureString` for new development. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-5.0#remarks)

P.P.S. If you're in control of both ends of this transaction (creating and verifying the hash), I'd suggest changing how you handle the username and password part, as the following will result in the same hash in the first step:

```
Username: bob     Password: bythechickenshed
Username: bobby   Password: thechickenshed
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try this. I'm using NetStandard2.1 for the project. Thanks for letting me know about `SecureString`. No, I just create an App for interacting with this server via Rest-API. The server it self is not made by me and I do not have access to the source code. Thank you!

Comment: Your example worked. Thank you so much for your quick help!